# Why do shifts have lower precedence than addition and subtraction in C?

Tags: c, operator-precedence

I sometimes find this inconvenient when doing bit manipulation (though I can't recall to mind any specific examples right now). I also find it conceptually confusing, since shifts are basically multiplication and division by powers of two.

I see that it can be convenient in C++, when using << to send output to an ostream, but of course that can't be used to explain how the order was originally fixed in C.

Comment: IMO: shifts do multiplication, so they should have the same precedence (or higher) of multiplication. Moreover, they aren't the only dumb choices of operator related grammar in C. All the `+= *=` would be better to be left-associative, so you could write `a += b += 4` to add stuff to `a` in-place (matters in C++). Then you could use that in C++ for a formatted output operator, which would work even better than today's `<<`, because `+=` has even lower precedence... But C++ did its own crimes in precedence choices. For example `.* ->*` should have had higher precedence than postfix operators...

Answer (score 2):

Because that's what the authors of the C language decided.

Use parentheses to avoid confusion.

Comment: Isn't there a 'better' answer? Not that this is not correct, but did the authors have a reason?

Comment: I believe he is asking "What the h*ll were they thinking?"  I have often wondered the same.

Comment: I think it's universally agreed that making these multiplicative operators have lower precedence than addition is one of the biggest mistakes of the C language, but it can't be fixed. Move along, nothing to see here...

Comment: @R..: `enum { FOO, BAR }; flags = FOO << 1 | BAR << 2;`. In this context, where AND/OR takes a place of being “constructive” rather than “additive”, shifts having a lower precedence than AND/OR actually makes sense. So it was probably a die rolling game when the authors made the precedence table. (Arguably, we'd make FOO<<1 a separate define/enum entry these days)

Comment: Note: C is based on preceding languages such as Algol.  In Algol shl, shr have _higher_ precedence than *, / rather than in C where << >> have lower precedence.