# Precedence while using right and left shift operators

Tags: c, bit-shift, operator-precedence

I want to know how the output of following C program is 32. Please provide me a step by step guidance on the same.

```
main()
{
    int a=4,b=2;
    a=b<<a+b>>2;
    printf("%d",a);
}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15953184/694576 http://stackoverflow.com/q/9370844/694576

Comment: side note ... this isn't valid C, make it `int main(void)` then it is ...

Answer (score 5):

Asking about *precedence*, `+` has higher precedence than `<<` and `>>`, so the expression is

```
b << (a + b) >> 2
```

evaluated as

```
2 << (4 + 2) >> 2 = 2 << 6 >> 2
```

Now, there's again to decide which part is evaluated first -- `<<` and `>>` have the same *precedence*, but *associativity* comes to the rescue, for `<<` and `>>` it is *left-to-right*, so this means the leftmost operator is evaluated first:

```
(2 << 6) >> 2 = 128 >> 2 = 32
```

**edit**: doing all in one step, respecting *precedence* and *associativity*, your original expression `b<<a+b>>2` reads the following fully parenthesized:

```
((b << (a + b)) >> 2
```

For future doubts, it's very helpful to have a [table showing both precedence and associativity](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). Or just use some "superfluous" parenthesis to make the expression more readable to humans ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
int a=4,b=2;
a=b<<a+b>>2;
```

Here b is 2  == (0000 0000 0010)

```
a = 2<<(4+2)>>2; // as ADD(+) is having higher precedence so first we will solve addtion.
a = 2 << 6 >> 2;

a = ((2 << 6) >> 2); //<<  >>, Associativity (left-to-right) so first solve (2 << 6).
```

Shifting 6 bits to left

```
After solving 2<<6  (0000 1000 0000)  == 128  
                          ^^^^ ^^   <-- left
```

Shifting 2 bits to right

```
Now 128>>2  (0000 0010 0000)  == 32.  
        Right -->  ^^
```

Comment: upvoting now because it's IMHO complete through code-comments. The display of bits might be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the disassembly of this code:

```
    31:                 int a = 4, b = 2;
00007FFE91FC449C C7 45 24 04 00 00 00 mov         dword ptr [rbp+24h],4  
00007FFE91FC44A3 C7 45 20 02 00 00 00 mov         dword ptr [rbp+20h],2  
    32:                 a = b << a + b >> 2;
00007FFE91FC44AA 8B 4D 24             mov         ecx,dword ptr [rbp+24h]  
00007FFE91FC44AD 8B 45 20             mov         eax,dword ptr [rbp+20h]  
00007FFE91FC44B0 03 C8                add         ecx,eax  
00007FFE91FC44B2 83 E1 1F             and         ecx,1Fh  
00007FFE91FC44B5 8B 45 20             mov         eax,dword ptr [rbp+20h]  
00007FFE91FC44B8 D3 E0                shl         eax,cl  
00007FFE91FC44BA 8B C8                mov         ecx,eax  
00007FFE91FC44BC C1 F9 02             sar         ecx,2  
00007FFE91FC44BF 89 4D 24             mov         dword ptr [rbp+24h],ecx
```

As you can see, the `+` operator is done first, and the `<<` and `>>` operators have the same precedence and have left to right associativity (and therefore executed from left to right) so your code can be simplified to:

```
main()
{
    int a = 4, b = 2;
    a = a + b; //6
    a = b << a; //128
    a = a >> 2; //32
    printf("%d", a);
}
```

***Note that there are no actual assignments to a in the function other than the last assignment and the decleration.***

And your code is the same as if you would write it as `a = b << (a + b) >> 2;`.

Comment: Very thorough, but translating the assembly back to C creates code with a different meaning -- the intermediate assignments to `a` are not specified in the original code and specifying them, *sequenced*, is not equivalent to the original.

Comment: I guess the compiler assumes that it doesn't damage the execution of the code so it's sort of optimization.

Comment: Yes, the assembly is a correct translation, as it exposes the exact *observable behavior*. I'm just saying translating it back to C, you introduce additional sequence points and your resulting code defines more than the original code did. I just wouldn't call this "simplified", that's all my comment was about :)

Comment: For sake of completeness, you still need to explain why `<<` took precedence over '>>'. In the C precedence table, they have the same precedence, and shift operators have *left-to-right associativity *  :)

Comment: I don't see why this answer is *downvoted* though ... the OP asked **how** the result comes to be `32`, not **why**. So an answer showing an example of assembly code (the technical view) is IMHO equally valid. I'd still prefer to explain it in terms of the C standard, just don't think this approach deserves a downvote.

Comment: @TamirVered you just introduced an error :( "have the same precedence (and therefore executed from left to right)" -- there are operators with *right to left* associativity. `<<` and `>>` are *left to right*, though.

Comment: @FelixPalmen I did not downvote but I agree, looking at a compiler's output seldomly helps understanding why code behaves in some way. C's undefined behavior often (not in this case) makes assembly not reflect the source. Optimization is another reason.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe yes, explaining the **why** is better, IMHO ... just saying as the question was asked, an answer showing the technical **how** is ok :)